# how to make a list transition smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

So far I have a button when clicked a list appears if clicked again the list closes but it is very robotic and not smooth here I will show you. I want to just understand how to make a smooth nice transition when someone clicks the button.

Here is the snippet.

```js
document.getElementById("show-list").onclick = function() {

  var l = document.getElementById('List');
  if (l.style.display == '') {
    l.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    l.style.display = '';
  }

};
```

```css
#List {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="show-list">Menu</button>
<ul id="List">Algorithms
  <li>Palindromes</li>
  <li>Factorialize Function</li>
  <li>Reverse A String</li>
  <li>Longest Word In String</li>
  <li>Title Case</li>
  <li>Return Largest Number In Array</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Use a framework that allows you to animate elements easier (like jQuery, which allows you to use [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/), [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/), etc) or animate your list's height/overflow using [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions). First and foremost though, consider doing some research - this question is likely too broad: What's a "smooth nice" transition? What have you already tried? What research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do that with css transition:

```js
document.getElementById("show-list").onclick = function() {

  var l = document.getElementById('List');
  if (l.style.height == 0) {
    l.style.height = 'auto';
    l.style.opacity = '1';
  } else {
    l.style.height = '0';
    l.style.opacity = '0';
  }

};
```

```css
#List {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<button id="show-list">Menu</button>
<ul id="List">Algorithms
  <li>Palindromes</li>
  <li>Factorialize Function</li>
  <li>Reverse A String</li>
  <li>Longest Word In String</li>
  <li>Title Case</li>
  <li>Return Largest Number In Array</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into some of the frameworks out there. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is freely available and extends Javascript to provide you with a ton of functionality. Tons of freely available frameworks have been built using jQuery, like Bootstrap and Semantic-UI that I'm sure provide you with the features you're looking for.

[Semantic-UI](https://semantic-ui.com/), for example, is super easy when it comes to doing a neat looking slide transition:

`$("#myElement").transition("slide down");`

jQuery also has expanded functionality through [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/); keep in mind that jQuery and jQuery-UI are two separate entities, though. jQuery-UI is built from jQuery. Perhaps the [Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) animations from jQuery-UI  suits your needs.